# awk to find overlaps

Tags: awk, overlap

I have a file with columns as shown below.

```
Group   Start        End
chr1    117132092    118875009
chr1    117027758    119458215
chr1    103756473    104864582
chr1    105093795    106219211
chr1    103354114    104747251
chr1    102741437    105235140
chr1    100090254    101094139
chr1    100426977    101614730
chr2    86644663     87767193
chr2    82473711     83636545
chr2    83896702     85079032
chr2    83876122     85091910
chr2    82943211     84350917
chr3    89410051     90485635
chr3    89405753     90485635
chr3    86491492     87593215
chr3    82507157     83738004
chr3    85059618     86362254
```

I would like to find the overlap between those coordinates in each group(grouped by chr1,chr2,chr3..).

The start and end coordinates has to be checked if there is atleast 50% overlap with the others in the same group. If there is atleast 50% overlap, the new start and end coordinates has to be reported in columns 3 and 4 (which is the range of the overlap region). If they don't overlap it has to report the original start and end in the columns 3 and 4.

To make it more clear, lets take the first two rows

```
                 117132092..........118875009
         117027758...........................119458215
```

Since both of them overlap atleast 50% with each other, the range of the overlap is reported as new start and new end in the output. And Row 3 and 4 doesn't overlap with others and so the original coordinates are reported as new start and new end in column 3 and 4. And again since rows 5 and 6 have 50% overlap with each other their range is reported as new start and new end in column 3 and 4.
 Here is the expected output:

```
Group   Start     End         NewStart   NewEnd   
chr1 117132092 118875009  117027758   119458215
chr1 117027758 119458215  117027758   119458215
chr1 103756473 104864582  103354114   104864582
chr1 105093795 106219211  105093795   106219211
chr1 103354114 104747251  102741437   105235140
chr1 102741437 105235140  102741437   105235140
chr1 100090254 101094139  100090254   101614730
chr1 100426977 101614730  100090254   101614730
chr2 86644663 87767193    86644663    87767193
chr2 82473711 83636545    82473711    83636545 
chr2 83896702 85079032    83876122    85091910
chr2 83876122 85091910    83876122    85091910
chr2 82943211 84350917    82943211    84350917
chr3 89410051 90485635    89405753    90485635
chr3 89405753 90485635    89405753    90485635
chr3 86491492 87593215    86491492    87593215
chr3 82507157 83738004    82507157    83738004
chr3 85059618 86362254    85059618    86362254
```

I have achieved this in R programming language but the original file is too huge and take a very long time to run. Could someone help this to do in awk.

Comment: Perhaps for the example you can use smaller numbers to reduce strain on the readers?

Comment: For example, how would the following `(start,end)`s map in the same group? `(1,4), (2,3), (1,2), (3,6), (2,5), (5,7)`  When there's more than a 50% overlap, does the greatest overlap "win"?  If there's more than one overlap or one overlap is equal to another, do you want the high or low range reported?

Comment: @MiserableVariable  i have used the same numbers in the example

Comment: Interesting problem, but that's a fair amount of free labour. What have you tried?

Comment: i have an r script and i have no experience in awk. I can post the r-script if it helps.

Comment: For row 3, you say the expected output is `chr1 103756473 104864582 103354114 104864582` since row 3 overlaps with row 5. But it also overlaps with row 6. Why do you choose row 5 and not row 6?

Comment: @HåkonHægland  You were very near to understand my problem. You were right that row 3 overlaps with both 5 and 6. But with row 6 the overlap is not greater that 50%. So it means there is >50% only with row 5. Therefore the min of start and max of end between row 3 and 5 is reported as new start and new end for row 3. Moreover the overlap should be reciprocal with each other.

Comment: I think @MiserableVariable 's and n0741337 's point was to rewrite your question using smaller numbers (3 digits max?, or at least the smallest possible for the problem). The numbers used in your question add considerable cognitive strain to what may be a simpler (than it looks) problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Gnu Awk version 4, you could try:

```
gawk -f a.awk file file
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
NR==FNR {
    if (FNR>1) {
        a[$1][++i]=$2
        b[$1][i]=$3
    }
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    fmt="%-7s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n"
    printf fmt,"Group","Start","End","NewStart","NewEnd" 
}
FNR>1{
    $4=$2; $5=$3
    n=checkInside($1,$2,$3)
    if (n>0) {
        ff=0; x=$2; y=$3
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            ar=a[$1][R[i]]; br=b[$1][R[i]];
            getIntersect($2,$3,ar,br)
            getLargest($2,$3,ar,br)
            ovl=((i2-i1)/($3-$2))*100;
            ovr=((i2-i1)/(br-ar))*100;
            if (ovl>50 && ovr>50) {
                if (r1<x) x=r1
                if (r2>y) y=r2
                ff=1
            }
        }
        if (ff) {
            $4=x; $5=y
        }
    }
    printf fmt,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5
}

function getLargest(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
    r1=(x1<=x2)?x1:x2
    r2=(y1>=y2)?y1:y2
}

function getIntersect(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
    if (x1>=x2 && x1<=y2) {
        i1=x1;
    } else {
        i1=x2;
    }
    i2=(y1<=y2)?y1:y2
}

function checkInside(g,x,y,i,j,x1,y1) {
    R["x"]=0
    for (i in a[g]) {
        x1=a[g][i]; y1=b[g][i];
        if ((x>=x1 && x<=y1) || (y>=x1 && y<=y1)) {
            if (!(x==x1 && y==y1))
                R[++j]=i
        }
    }
    return j
}
```

Output:

```
Group  Start     End       NewStart  NewEnd    
chr1   117132092 118875009 117027758 119458215 
chr1   117027758 119458215 117027758 119458215 
chr1   103756473 104864582 103354114 104864582 
chr1   105093795 106219211 105093795 106219211 
chr1   103354114 104747251 102741437 105235140 
chr1   102741437 105235140 102741437 105235140 
chr1   100090254 101094139 100090254 101614730 
chr1   100426977 101614730 100090254 101614730 
chr2   86644663  87767193  86644663  87767193  
chr2   82473711  83636545  82473711  83636545  
chr2   83896702  85079032  83876122  85091910  
chr2   83876122  85091910  83876122  85091910  
chr2   82943211  84350917  82943211  84350917  
chr3   89410051  90485635  89405753  90485635  
chr3   89405753  90485635  89405753  90485635  
chr3   86491492  87593215  86491492  87593215  
chr3   82507157  83738004  82507157  83738004  
chr3   85059618  86362254  85059618  86362254
```

Comment: @user1779730 Ok, hope you have Gnu Awk version 4 :) You cannot replace `printf` as you suggest.. In your suggestion `printf` will receive only 3 arguments, but the `fmt` string requires 5 argument..

Comment: I have a small concern. If you look at row 5, it overlaps with row 3 and row 6 and the new start for row 5 should be 102741437 because it is the minimum of start in row 3,5 and 6 and new end should be 105235140 as it is the maximum of end in row 3,5 and 6.

Comment: @user1779730 I have to think a little bit :)

Comment: @user1779730 So if there are `N` overlaps, it should consider all of them, not only the one with the largest percentage overlap?

Comment: @user1779730 What if 2 overlaps are greater than 50% and 2 are below 50%?

Comment: The overlap should be reciprocal. If, for row 3 there are N overlaps >50%. Then it should fulfill the reciprocal overlap. i.e. N rows should also overlap > 50%. If the reciprocal overlap is fulfilled by only x rows with row 3 then these x rows should have the min of start and max of end as new start and end coordinates. The N-x rows will have the same old coordinates as new start and end.

Comment: @user1779730 I will be busy for the next couple of hours.. But I will have a look at it during the day.. So be patient :)(

Comment: @user1779730 What do you exactly mean by `reciprocal`?

Comment: Row 3 overlaps with row 5 and row 6. Lengths of row 3,5 and 6 are 104864582-103756473=1108109 ,104747251-103354114=1393137 and 105235140-102741437=2493703. Overlap % of row3 with row5 is (intersect length of row 3 and row 5)/length of row3. Reciprocal % is (intersect length of row 3 and row 5)/length of row5. If both Overlap and reciprocal are >50% then for row 3 the new start and end will be the min of start and max of end from row 3 and 5. If row 3 does not fulfill this overlap and reciprocal criteria with row 6, then row 6 will have its original coordinates.

Comment: @user1779730 Let me see.. What do you mean by `intersect length of row 3 and row 5` ?

Comment: since there is an intersection between row 3 and 5, intersection length= min(end3,end5)-max(start3,start5)

Comment: `Overlap3 =L/(end3-start3)` where L is intersect length, `Overlap5=L/(end5-start5)`. If overlap3 and overlap5 are >50% then for row 3 the new start and end will be the min of start and max of end from row 3 and 5.

Comment: @user1779730 Then `intersect` is more like a union of the two intervals? (It is not the common usage of the term intersection) See: http://www.themathlab.com/geometry/section2/union%20and%20intersection.htm

Comment: Sorry. U were right, I might have used the wrong term. But the logic behind L is, `L= min(end3,end5)-max(start3,start5)`

Comment: @user1779730 But then the intersection might be larger than length of row 3? And you can get an overlap that is larger than 100%?

Comment: No,it cannot be larger than. Seems it is getting complicated. Here is what i need. Let me illustrate for row 3 and 5. `L=min(end3,end5)-max(start3,start5)=min(104864582,104747251)-max(103756473,103354114)=990778.  Overlap3=L/(end3-start3)=990778/(104864582-103756473)=84.1% Overlap5=L/(end5-start5)=990778/(104747251-103354114)=71.1%`.  So, always L will be less than the original length.

Comment: @user1779730 Ok I see, then you were right.. It is an intersection after all :)

Comment: @user1779730 Ok, now I have modified a little bit in my code. Here is the new output: http://pastebin.com/7HSbJ1rS . Does that look better?

Comment: Yes, it looks perfect. Could u post the new code. However this is a sample file. The original file has a total of 18 columns with these 3 columns present at random. I can assign the column numbers based on my file. So, if i want to print the new columns as 19th and 20th columns, fmt should have 20 arguments. could fmt be written in a different format

Comment: @user1779730 Great! You can try `sprintf` instead of `printf`.. I am not sure what you have in mind. I will update my answer with the new code..

Comment: I tried: `gawk -f overlap.awk test.txt output.txt` but it says
`gawk: overlap.awk:6: fatal: cannot open file output.txt for reading (No such file or directory)` i tried by swapping the arguments but similar error.

Comment: +1 for good looking solution, tech support AND free consulting. Good luck to all.

Comment: @user1779730 Try `gawk -f overlap.awk test.txt test.txt > output.txt`

Comment: I checked the code. Initially the output looked good but at some stage it is going wrong.

Comment: @user1779730 Ok, we can have a look at it to morrow, I go to sleep now :)

Comment: @user1779730 Thanks for the nice explanation! Here is an updated version: http://pastebin.com/bRGhLMAm . I believe this should solve the problems..

Comment: @user1779730 In the code, `ovl` and `ovr` are the overlap and reciprocal overlap.. For instance, you could try `ovl=((i2-i1)/($3-$2+1))*100;`

Comment: @user1779730 You are welcome.. Maybe you could update your question also.. with repsect to, for instance, the definition of overlaps and reciprocal overlaps.. Then it will be easier for later visitors to see the connection between the question and the answer? Have a nice day!

Comment: I need to separate the new start and new end columns with tabs.

Comment: @user1779730 Try `fmt="%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t"`

Comment: @user1779730 Thanks for the file.. It looks strange.. How large is the full file?

Comment: @user1779730 Thanks. I will have a look at it.. Could you put back the first file? I forgot to download it (the file `error.txt`)..

Comment: Here you go: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g8a529b6f41ee1ee59994526599610d3c9ca2254db

Comment: @user1779730 You say that the new start and end are `completely new` when run on the whole file.. But the whole file contains more elements in each group, so I think it would not be very surprising if the new start and ends are changed when run on the whole file?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But for instance in the error.txt file, the end coordinate for the first row is "119783223". And i tried to find to which element this corresponds to and it is not present anywhere in the file. So i wonder, from where the value "119783223" came from.

Comment: @user1779730 Ok.. But note that the first line in the input file must be a header line.. From the file you sent me, it seems that the header line is missing..

Comment: The error is not just with first line. By the term "Completely new", i mean the new value is not present anywhere else in the file. The new value should come from the overlapping elements. So the new value should correspond to some element but this is not the case here. First 7 New end coordinates in the error.txt file shows more such instances. and 8th new coordinate is correct and again  9,10.... new coordinates cannot be found.

Comment: @user1779730 So here is what I got: First line in large file: `1     117132092 118875009`.. 1st line in output: `1 117132092 118875009 116906871 119458215`. First new start is therefore: `116906871`. This value is not completely new. It can be found on line 2714 in the large file..

Comment: Im embarassed with myself. I would have sorted the file and looked into.

Comment: Could you let understand what exactly `ar=a[$1][R[i]]; br=b[$1][R[i]]` mean.

Comment: I have a new problem when i copied the code from linux to MAC OSX. I have posted the problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026044/awk-script-change-in-format-from-linux-to-mac . could u please help further to fix this.

Comment: @user1779730 Yes it is correct. This code uses arrays of arrays from Gnu Awk version 4. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays-of-Arrays