# awk script change in format from Linux to MAC

Tags: linux, macos

I have an awk script with the lines below:

```
NR==FNR {
    if (FNR>1) {
        a[$3][++i]=$6
        b[$3][i]=$7
    }
    next
}
```

When i use the script it says

```
awk: syntax error at source line 3 source file ../Overlap.awk
 context is
        >>>  a[$3][ <<<  
awk: illegal statement at source line 3 source file ../Overlap.awk
```

The script is copied from a linux machine to MAC OSX and the problem arised. Could someone help to fix this.

Comment: This code uses arrays of arrays from Gnu Awk version 4. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays-of-Arrays.

Answer (score 2):

AWK doesn't support multidimensional arrays the way *most* languages do, or at least the way we're used to. Here is how you can access indexes in associative arrays using AWK:

```
NR==FNR {
    if (FNR>1) {
        a[$3, ++i]=$6
        b[$3, i]=$7
    }
    next
}
```

You can read more about AWK and multidimensional arrays [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-23) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multi_002ddimensional.html#Multi_002ddimensional).

Comment: but it worked in linux machine and i wonder why doesn't it work in MAC OSX

Comment: @user1779730: In general, different platforms use different flavors of awk that differ in behavior and features. For instance, OSX uses FreeBSD awk, while some Linux flavor use gawk, while other use mawk. **However**: All flavors mentioned do NOT support the separate-subscripts syntax; it's also not in the POSIX spec (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/awk.html); even if there is a flavor out there where that works - please tell us what it is- you should avoid this syntax for the sake of portability.

Comment: Yes this is a good advice, also note that it is possible to install Gnu Awk version 4 on OSX as described in this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/QM51VPAlw4I